# Papa Rudin $6.16$ theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

There is the theorem:
Suppose $1\leq p \lt \infty $, $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite positive measure on $X$, and $\phi$ is a bounded linear functional on $L^{p}(\mu)$. Then there is a unique $g \in L^{q}(\mu)$, where $q$ is the exponent conjugate to $p$, such that

$$\phi(f) = \int_{X} fg \ d\mu \ \ (f \in L^{p}(\mu)). $$

Moreover, if $\Phi$ and $g$ are related as mentioned above, we have $$ ||\phi|| = ||g||_{q} . $$

There is the proof: The uniqueness of $g$ is clear, for if $g$ and $g’$ satisfy the relation with $\phi$, then the integral of $g-g’$ over any measurable set $E$ of finite measure is $0$ ( as we see by taking $\chi_{E}$ for $f$), and the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$ implies therefore that $g - g’ = 0$ a.e.

Next, if the relation between $g$ and $\phi$ holds, Hölder‘s inequality implies
$$ ||\phi|| \leq ||g||_{q} . $$

I don’t understand how does Hölder’s inequality imply the last inequality.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One definition of the operator norm is $\|\phi\| = \sup_{\|f\|_p\leq 1} |\phi(f)|$. So by Holder, if $\|f\|_p \leq 1$,
$$|\phi(f)| \leq \int |fg|\,d\mu \leq \|f\|_p\|g\|_q \leq \|g\|_q,$$
and taking the sup over all such $f$ gives $\|\phi\| \leq \|g\|_q$.

Comment: Thank you. please check it too https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4888934/papa-rudin-6-16-theorem-case-2

Answer (score 2):

Holder's inequality states that if $f\in L^p(\mu)$ and $g\in L^q(\mu)$, then $fg\in L^1(\mu)$ and we have

$$
\|fg\|_1\leq\|f\|_p\|g\|_q
$$

Also note that

$$
|\phi(f)|=\left|\int_Xfg\,d\mu\right|\leq\int_X|fg|\,d\mu=\|fg\|_1
$$

Depending on your definition of the norm of $\phi$, we take here

$$
\|\phi\|=\sup_{\|f\|_p=1}|\phi(f)|\leq\sup_{\|f\|_p=1}\|f\|_p\|g\|_q=\|g\|_q
$$

This gives you your inequality.

Comment: Thank you. please check it too https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4888934/papa-rudin-6-16-theorem-case-2

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi:E\to F$ and $\Vert\phi(x)\Vert_F\le K\Vert x\Vert_E$ then by definition we have $\Vert\phi\Vert\le K$.

Here $E=L^p(\mu)$, and $F=\mathbb R$. For all $f\in L^p(\mu)$, $\phi(f)=\int_Xfg\,d\mu$, so by Hölders inequality,
$$
\vert\phi(f)\vert\le\Vert g\Vert_q\Vert f\Vert_p,
$$
hence $\Vert\phi\Vert\le\Vert g\Vert_q$ (here $\Vert g\Vert_q=K$ from my notation above).

Comment: $\phi\in (L^p(\mu))^\prime$, hence $\phi:L^p(\mu)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot for pointing that out, I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you. please check it too https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4888934/papa-rudin-6-16-theorem-case-2