# Papa Rudin $6.16$ theorem case 2.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

There is the theorem:
Suppose $1\leq p \lt \infty $, $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite positive measure on $X$, and $\varphi$ is a bounded linear functional on $L^{p}(\mu)$. Then there is a unique $g \in L^{q}(\mu)$, where $q$ is the exponent conjugate to $p$, such that

$$\varphi(f) = \int_{X} fg \ d\mu \ \ (f \in L^{p}(\mu)). $$

Moreover, if $\varPhi$ and $g$ are related as mentioned above, we have $$ ||\varphi|| = ||g||_{q} . $$

There is the proof:
[image]

[image]

I don't understand how we get that $\int_{x} |G|^{q} d \tilde{\mu} = ||\Psi||^{q}$ in $(11)$.

I also don't understand why do we have $||g||_{\infty} = ||G||_{\infty} = ||\Psi||$ if $p \gt 1 $.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your last question you asked how to show that $\Vert\varphi\Vert = \Vert g \Vert_q$. Any reason why that proof doesn't work to show that $\Vert\Psi\Vert = \Vert G \Vert_q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the relation
$$\Psi(F) = \int_X FG \,\mathrm{d}\tilde{\mu}$$
for $F\in L^p(\tilde{\mu})$ and $G\in L^q(\tilde{\mu})$ with $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$ it easily follows that
$$\Vert\Psi\Vert = \Vert G \Vert_q.$$
If $p = 1$, then $q = \infty$, and sending $q\rightarrow\infty$ in the equality above yields
$$\Vert\Psi\Vert = \Vert G\Vert_\infty.$$

Comment: How does it follow easily that $||\psi|| = ||G||_{q}$ ? Can you please write it explicitly?

Comment: It's the same line of argument as for $\varphi$, there is basically no difference, only that you work with the measure $\tilde{\mu}$ instead of $\mu$. (see your other question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4887937/papa-rudin-6-16-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1)